# How to map a relationship between a java object and map of java object

Tags: java, hibernate, hashmap

I have a java object called

```
public class MyObject {

@ElementCollection 
Map<Integer, AnotherJavaObject> customMap;
}

public class AnotherObject {

String value;
int value;
}
```

Is this possible to achoeve with hibernate? Is another Object an Entity?
what should the mapping be in class MyObject?

After reading up I annotated the AnotherObject as follows

```
@Entity(name = "AnotherObject")
public class AnotherObject {

@ManyToOne
Myobject myObject;
}

And in the MyOBject class created a @OneToMany mappng as

@OneToMany(mappedBy="myObject)
AnotherObject anotherObject;
```

But this goves me an error

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: MyObject.anotherObject
```

So I got past this error by registering the class but I am getting this error on a merge

```
object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
public class MyObject {

    int id;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="AuthorBookGroup",
        joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_myobject", referencedColumnName="id")},
        inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="fk_anotherobject", referencedColumnName="id")})
    @MapKey(name = "value2")
    Map<Integer, AnotherJavaObject> customMap;
}

public class AnotherObject {

    String value1;
    int value2;
    int id;
}
```